# How to get month and year from complex date

Tags: r, date

My date column shows like this: "27 May 2016 10:08:13 AM"

All of my attempts result in a column filled with NA.

I have tried many things like:

```
df$Create_Month <- format(as.Date(df$`Create Date`, format="%d/%b/%Y %I:%M:%s %p"),"%Y-%m"))
df$Create_Month <- format(as.POSIXct(df$`Create Date`, format="%d/%b/%Y %I:%M:%s %p"),"%Y-%m"))
df[,"Create_Month"] <- format(as.Date(df$`Create Date`, format="%d/%b/%Y %I:%M:%s %p"),"%Y-%m"))
df[,"Create_Month"] <- format(df$`Create Date`,"%Y-%m"))
```

and variations on these, including dplyr piping, mutate, lubridate and etcetera.
Output in Terminal Is:

```
R> format(df$`Create Date`,"%Y %m"))
Error in format.default(Infocards$`Create Date`, "%Y %m") : 
invalid 'trim' argument

R> as.POSIXct("27 May 2016 10:08:13 AM", tz="EST", "%d %b %Y %i:%m:%s %p")
[1] NA

R> as.Date("27 May 2016 10:08:13 AM", "%d %b %Y %i:%m:%s %p")
[1] NA
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%i`, `%m`, `%s` should be upper case

```
as.POSIXct("27 May 2016 10:08:13 AM", tz="EST", "%d %b %Y %I:%M:%S %p")
[1] "2016-05-27 10:08:13 EST"
```

With this the `format` would work

```
format(as.POSIXct("27 May 2016 10:08:13 AM", tz="EST", 
  "%d %b %Y %I:%M:%S %p"), "%Y %m")
[1] "2016 05"
```

Comment: Thanks, this does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Try `parse_date()` function from `parse_date` package:

```
library(parsedate)
parse_date(x)

[1] "2016-05-27 10:08:13 UTC"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
currentdate=datetime.date.today()
currentmonthName=currentdate.strftime("%B")
print(currentdate)
print(currentmonthname)
```

The strftime() function is used to convert date and time objects to their string representation. It takes one or more input of formatted code and returns the string representation.

%Brepresents the full month name like January, February and so on.